# Using FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP to instatiate an activity that was already ended with finish();

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a login screen, which on successfully login, is taken to LandingPage, and from LandingPage, I navigate to LastActivity.

My navigation need me to come back to LandingPage if I press backbutton on LastActivity. So i did not use `finish()` while firing intenet to start LastActivity.

Clicking logOut button on LastActivity should take me to LoginPage, and it does, but if I press back button on LoginPage, it takes me back to LandingPage. Which is not desired behavior.
This is code I used to navigate to activity -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
```

am I using this flag wrong?

Edit -
flow of activity is -
LoginActivity -> LandingPage -> lastActivity
on logging out from last activity, it should go to loginActivity.

Comment: Did you call finish() when launching LandingPage? If you did, just remove it.

Comment: Yes, in the intent, which calls LandingPage, I called finish(), but I guess in that case even my 'LoginActivity' will not be finished. Am I right?

Comment: If from LoginActivity you call startActivity(.., LandingPage) and then call finish(), then your LoginActivity would be destroyed and the flag CLEAR_TOP is useless since there is no LoginActivity in the stack.

Comment: @HoanNguyen absoultely.. And that's why I am finding solution to this bottleneck, any idea?

Comment: In the LoginActivity starts the LandingPage but do not called finish(), then your code would be fine.

Comment: if I don't call 'finish()' on Login activity then it will come back to LoginActivity if I pressed back Button..

Comment: So you do not want to go back to LoginActivity when back pressed from LandingPage? You want to go back to home screen?

Answer (score 0):

What you  have is this (if I understand correctly):

LandingPage -> LastActivity -> LoginPage

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` is helpful if you want to go back to a previous activity and clear the top of the back stack. However, what you're doing is accidentally allowing yourself to go back to a point at the bottom of your back stack.

**Edit:** Have you attempted to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` when logging out? This should clear all other activities from the stack. Note this should be used in conjunction with the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag.

Comment: I am checking this flag_activity_clear_task. btw my activity cycle is LoginActivity > landingPage -> LastActivity.
When I Logout from last activity, it should go to LoginActivity automatically without keeping anything in stack.